# Moving CSV file to different server using SAS

Tags: csv, sas

I am not very technical so please bear with me while I try to explain the problem.  We have a daily scheduled job that kicks off a SAS program on a Unix server.  The program analyzes data and spits out a CSV file which gets stored on the server and then emailed to me.  I then manually download the file from email and upload it to a utility to process the file.  I am looking for a way to bypass the manual steps and instead have the SAS program upload the CSV file directly to a folder on the server for the file processing utility.

So given that the csv file is stored on the server that SAS is connected to (/user/folder/file.csv) how can I transport this file to another folder (/inbox) on another server (server2.test.com)?

Here is what I have so far, but I think I am missing something because the file isn't making it to the folder:

```
proc import file="/user/folder/file.csv"    
            dbms=csv out=file1 replace;     
run;

filename outdir ftp "/inbox"  DIR
                    host="server2.test.com" 
                    user="username" pass="pwd";

data _null_;
   file outdir(file1);
   put file1;
run;
```

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  I would define one filename for the reading the CSV file and one for writing to the FTP server.

```
filename in "/user/folder/file.csv";
filename outdir ftp "/inbox"  DIR
                host="server2.test.com" 
                user="username" pass="pwd"
;
```

Then copy the file.

```
data _null_;
  infile in;
  file outdir("file.csv");
  input;
  put _infile_;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I ran the program and it didn't have any errors, but when I connect to the server with Filezilla, I don't see the file stored in the inbox folder.  Any idea why it wouldn't work?

Comment: The notes from the data step should show you how many lines where read and written.  Can you create such a file on that server using FileZilla? Perhaps you are trying to write to a place where you do not have permission to write.  Also if you used syntax for the `FILE` statement like in your example without the quotes then SAS might have added `.dat` extension on the file it wrote.

Comment: The notes said that the records were read and written successfully: 
NOTE: 5 records were read from the infile IN.
      The minimum record length was 34.
      The maximum record length was 106.
NOTE: A total of 5 records were written to the file library OUTDIR.
      The minimum record length was 34.
      The maximum record length was 106.
NOTE: 5 records were written to the file OUTDIR("file.csv").
      The minimum record length was 34.
      The maximum record length was 106.